# How to Get a Monitor's Scaling

Tags: java, swt, dpi

There is probably a really simple API for it, but I can't find any method on  `Monitor` to return the current scaling of the monitor.

I found:

```
DPIUtil.getDeviceZoom();
```

But that's a static constant, so it's not a monitor's scaling (but the primary monitor's?).

`Device#getDPI()` seems to change with the scaling, too, but there is only one display for an application, so that's no help either.

How do I get a monitor's scaling in SWT?

Comment: Judging by Eclipse bug [509534](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509534) there currently isn't any support for this.